# phpBB - Reducing Spam

Tags: forum, phpbb

I've installed phpBB Forums last week and the past 2 days I've been getting users sign up and posting spam chinese emails on each topic.

I have:-

- Added captcha on registration
- Made sure users have to verify subscription by email before allowing
  to post

What else can I do to stop this from happening?

I've banned their IP addresses but this doesn't stop them from using a proxy to keep spamming the forums.

I've read I can block all chinese IP addresses through ACP but is this the best step to block all this?

Seems to be all chinese spam at the minute, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I was going to recommend just [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) but then I saw this [Blog Post by a Michel Kramer](http://www.michel-kraemer.com/5-anti-spam-measures-for-phpbb3)

Comment: Do they always choose the predefined timezone when registering (or other similar things)? I've heard many bots leave the dropdown for the timezone and the pre selected timezone is in the middle of the pacific nobody lives. Or simply add some more custom form fields in the registration that require to prove they are not bots. Anything like that to block those bots. If those attacks are formed by real humans, it's getting hard. If your forum does not support Chinese as language (I assume), there might be a way to abort post creation when a Chinese sign is within the content of the post.